# Trouble with friends: How to grant private access to an inner class?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, friend

Here I have a simplified version of a linked-list implementation I have been working on. I would like to keep a count of component elements (nodes) as a private member, and then let the `Component` constructor and destructor completely handle the variable `count`.

However, I'm getting a compiler error (VS2015) disallowing access to `count` by any member functions (including the constructor and destructor) that I have in `Component`:

'count': undeclared identifier

Why does the `friend` declaration not grant that access in this case?

```
class Outer {
private:
    class Component;
    friend class Component;
public:
    Outer() : count(0) {}
    unsigned int size() {
        return count;
    }
    void methodThatCreatesComponents() {
        entryPoint = new Component(nullptr);
        // I don't want to have to write ++count; every time I construct
    }
    void methodThatDeletesComponents() {
        delete entryPoint;
        // I don't want to have to write --count; every time I delete
        entryPoint = nullptr;
    }
private:
    unsigned int count;
    Component* entryPoint;
    class Component {
    public:
        Component(Component* next) {
            ++count;
        }
        ~Component() {
            --count;
        }
    private:
        Component* next;
    };
};
```

Comment: C++ doesn't automatically allow inner classes to have access to the outer classes. See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types).

Comment: Second, `class Component() {...};` should be `class Component {...}` (no parentheses).

Comment: @callyalater Which is why I thought using friend would work, but thanks for the link, that helps.

Comment: @callyalater The parentheses were a typo when I wrote up the question. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify `count` with proper scope.

I am guessing that `count` is expected to be a `static` member of `Outer`. Then, you an use:

```
Component(Component* next) {
   ++Outer::count;
}
~Component() {
   --Outer::count;
}
```

If `count` is supposed to be a non-`static` member of `Outer`, `Component` needs an instance of `Object` to be able to access the `count` member variable.

Comment: Won't work as `count` is not a static member of `Outer`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Throws error "illegal reference to non-static member Outer::count."

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov, I assumed, incorrectly, that `count` is a `static` member variable.

Comment: @RSahu the parentheses was a typo, not in the original code. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access private members of outer class via a pointer to the outer class. The compiler errors are not about level of access, they are probably stating something like "count was not declared in the scope".

The following should solve the problem:

```
class Component {
public:
    Component(Outer* outer, Component* next) : outer(outer) {
        ++outer->count;
    }
    ~Component() {
        --outer->count;
    }
private:
    Outer* outer;
    Component* next;
};
```

P.S. There is also a hacky way to get a pointer to an outer class via `offsetof`:

```
class Component {
public:
    Component(Component* next) : outer(outer) {
        ++outer()->count;
    }
    ~Component() {
        --outer()->count;
    }
private:
    Outer* outer() {
        return (void*)this - offsetof(Outer, entryPoint);
    }

    Outer* outer;
    Component* next;
};
```

Comment: This would work, but is rather ugly. Do I really need to pass `this` as a parameter every time I call the Constructor? Plus, this adds an extra pointer of memory space to every instance of Component... I would almost rather just pair mutator statements with my constructors/deletes.

Comment: @Aposhian Now your question is rather about the design than C++ language. If you want to modify `count` every time the node is inserted/deleted, I'd prefer having functions `insert()` and `remove()` in the `class Outer` which would do `count++` and `count--`. If `Component` represents a node of a linked list, then IMO it should not know anything about its container, including its size.

Comment: @Aposhian it shouldn't be the job of `Outer::Component` to adjust a member variable of `Outer` in the first place IMO. Like Oleg remarked, put insert and remove functions in the `Outer` class. Presumably the user is not going to see the `Component` class anyhow, so why bother with this friend contraption. Make `Component` a simple struct and do the logic in `Outer`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think that I came up with a suitable method that works around the fact that `Component` can't know about about the instance of `Outer` that it is inside without storing a `this` for each instance. Using helper functions:

```
class Outer {
private:
    class Component;
public:
    Outer() : count(0) {}

    unsigned int size() {
        return count;
    }
    void methodThatCreatesComponents() {
        // other functionality
        entryPoint = createComponent(nullptr);
    }
    void methodThatDeletesComponents() {
        // other functionality
        deleteComponent(entryPoint);
    }
private:
    unsigned int count;
    Component* entryPoint;
    class Component {
    public:
        Component(Component* next) : next(next) {}
        ~Component() {}
    private:
        Component* next;
    };
    Component* createComponent(Component* next) {
        ++count;
        return new Component(next);
    }
    void deleteComponent(Component*& toDelete) {
        --count;
        delete toDelete;
        toDelete = nullptr;
    }
};
```

This way I don't have to worry about modifying the count every time I construct or destroy, or a deluge of `this` or other structures intended to compromise the nested object structure. The other answers definitely helped me see what was wrong with my perception of inner classes. Ciao!